# Replace the last half in every line of a file with the last half of corresponding line in another file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have two files A and B. Every line in both files is considered an item. The format of every item is fixed, consisting of a key and description, separated by a space. as shown in the example below.

```
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000027_0000104 /users/documents/ark
```

The first part, `UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000027_0000104`, is the key, and the last part,`/users/documents/ark`, is the description. File A and B have 1000 and 100000 items, respectively. Every key can be divided into two parts: index (for example: `UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2`) and time stamp (for example: `0000027_0000104`) in our example.  There is no rule about digits in the time stamp. The character between index and time stamp is fixed as `_`. Every key is unique, and every index is also unique in the same file. Every index included in file A also occurred in file B with a different time stamp. As shown in a simple example below.

File A

```
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000000_0000119 /users/documents/ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000027_0000104 /users/documents/ark2
```

File B

```
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/documents/ark3
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/documents/ark4
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/documents/ark5
```

I want to replace the description corresponding to the same index in file B with the description corresponding to the index in file A. The result in the example is shown below.

File B

```
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/documents/ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/documents/ark2
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/documents/ark5
```

How to achieve this target?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and focus on the problem you are facing. (Btw I did not downvote.)

Comment: Are the files sorted?  If so, then perhaps the `join` command is what you want.

Comment: The file is not sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR{
        split($1,p,"_")
        a[p[1]"_"p[2]] = $NF
        next
    } 
    split($1,b,"_") && (b[1]"_"b[2] in a){ 
        $NF = a[b[1]"_"b[2]]
    }1
' FileA FileB

UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/documents/ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/documents/ark2
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/documents/ark5
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's|([^_]*_).*( .*)|/^\1/s# .*#\2#|' fileA | sed -f - fileB
```

Build a sed script from fileA to apply to fileB.

Each line in fileA is turned into a match and a substitution. The index is used as a match and its description is used in the substitution then this is applied to fileB. Those lines that match will have the description from fileA.

N.B. The use of alternate delimiters in both substitution commands. If the description is likely to have the `#` character then use another character as a delimiter that is not present in any description.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](https://nongnu.org/txr) Lisp:

```
$ txr subst.tl filea fileb
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/documents/ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/documents/ark2
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/documents/ark5
```

Code:

```
(tree-bind (filea fileb) *args*
  (let ((h (hash)))
    (with-stream (s (open-file filea))
      (whilet ((line (get-line s)))
        (match `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @path` line
          (set [h `@a-@b-@c`] path))))
    (with-stream (s (open-file fileb))
      (whilet ((line (get-line s)))
        (match `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @path` line
          (put-line `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @(or [h `@a-@b-@c`] path)`))))))
```

Or, using `awk` macro to scan the files; but otherwise the same approach:

```
(awk
  (:let (h (hash)))
  ((= fnr nr)
   (match `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @path` rec
     (set [h `@a-@b-@c`] path))
   (next))
  ((match `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @path` rec
    (prn `@a-@{b}_@{c}_@d @(or [h `@a-@b-@c`] path)`))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = substr($1,1,length($1)-16) }
NR == FNR {
    sub(/[^ ]+/,"")
    map[key] = $0
    next
}
key in map {
    $0 = $1 map[key]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk FileA FileB
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/documents/ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/documents/ark2
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/documents/ark5
```

The above will work even if any of your "descriptions" ever contain white space, e.g. given this input:

```
$ head File[AB]
==> FileA <==
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000000_0000119 /users/saved documents/this    is     interesting ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000027_0000104 /users/saved documents/ark2

==> FileB <==
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/saved documents/ark3
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/saved documents/and    so     is   this   ark4
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/saved documents/and   this   too  ark5
```

we still get the desired output:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk FileA FileB
UASPCH-XCF02-SP062-XXB2CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000002_0000118 /users/saved documents/this    is     interesting ark1
UASPCH-XCF02-XXB1CF02-UACF02-ih_CW100M2_0000026_0000107 /users/saved documents/ark2
UASPCH-XXM16-XXXB1M16-XUAM16-ih_CW100M3_0000039_0000129 /users/saved documents/and   this   too  ark5
```